# Как фиксировано с позиционированный элемент прижать с краю блока-обертики?

Tags: html, css

Есть элемент .navbar, которому задано свойство position: fixed и нужно, чтобы этот элемент был прижат к краю блока .wrapper, но когда я задаю для .navbar свойство width: 100%, то он уходит за пределы экрана, причем начало берет от левого края wrapper-а. Как сделать так, чтобы ширина .navbar упиралась в ширину wrapper-а и при уменьшении ширины экрана .navbar оставался прижатым к краю блока-обертки?

**PS navbar обозначен красным, чтобы лучше понимать, где его границы**

Сам сайт http://cc48161.tmweb.ru/

Весь код jsfiddle.net/09qc4kLt/

Как у меня
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Как надо

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```css
.navbar {
    position: fixed;
    display: flex;
    justify-content:  flex-end;
    top: 50%;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    z-index: 1000;
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="arrow up"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-up"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#main" class="dot active" data-scroll="main">
                            <span>Главная</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#about_us" class="dot" data-scroll="about_us">
                            <span>О нас</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#services" class="dot" data-scroll="services">
                            <span>Услуги</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#sequence" class="dot" data-scroll="sequence">
                            <span>Порядок работы</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#stages" class="dot" data-scroll="stages">
                            <span>Этапы работы</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#portfolio" class="dot" data-scroll="portfolio">
                            <span>Портфолио</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#news" class="dot" data-scroll="news">
                            <span>Новости</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#contacts" class="dot" data-scroll="contacts">
                            <span>Контакты</span>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="#" class="arrow down"><i class="far fa-arrow-alt-circle-down"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </nav>
```

Answer (score 0):

Не понял зачем тут в принципе `position: fixed`, но допустим.
Поскольку при таком позиционировании дочерний элемент выпадает из потока, вам нужно рассчитать его ширину самостоятельно. Если ширина блока должна быть привязана к размерам родителя, нужно смотреть css родителя - за ширину там отвечает следующий код:

```
width: 100%;
max-width: 1800px;
padding: 30px 60px;
box-sizing: border-box;
```

Т.е. это вам нужно перенести в расчет ширины `navbar`:

```
width: calc(100% - 2 * 60px);
max-width: calc(1800px - 2 * 60px);
```

Comment: ну как зачем? Как иначе сделать так, чтобы элемент постоянно был на виду при скроллинге страниц?

Comment: И спасибо за помощь!

Comment: Но у меня возникла еще одна проблема: теперь navbar перекрывает контент, пробовал играться с z-index и переместить его в самый низ кода, но это все не то. Залил актуальную версию  http://cc48161.tmweb.ru/

Comment: @Edroy чтобы вам помочь нужно понимать как вы хотите, чтобы это работало. Возможно вопрос решается проще или по другому.

Comment: я хочу чтобы navbar был фиксированным и при этом не перекрывал другой контент и не был перекрыт другим контентом

Comment: @Edroy Т.е. остальной контент должен как бы обтекать фиксированный элемент? Ну, это возможно теоретически, но тут вам нужны серьезные расчеты c измерением размеров элементов на js. Причем результаты этих изменений будут зависеть от css, что будет приводить к повторному рендеру страницы. Задача в общем нетривиальная. Вряд ли кто-то готов будет ее решить в рамках бесплатной помощи.